# How Get start Hour and End Hour from a datetime field SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have 2 tables in sql Server 2008. The source table have 2 fields: `userid` and `date` (datetime). The target table have 4 fields: - `userid`, `Day`, `startHour` and `EndHour` -.  I need to find repeated days to extract into the two fields ( startHour end EndHour) in the target table without repeat the day.

Source table:

```
UserID TheDate
------ -----------------------
0001   2014-07-23 08:18:02.000
0001   2014-07-23 16:04:02.000
0002   2014-07-23 08:00:00.000
0003   2014-07-23 09:00:00.000
```

Target table:

```
UserID TheDate    StartHour        EndHour
------ ---------- ---------------- ----------------
0001   2014-07-23 08:18:02         16:04:02
0002   2014-07-23 08:00:00         NULL
0003   2014-07-23 09:00:00         NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID
      ,DateOnly
      ,CONVERT(time, MIN(TheDate)) AS StartHour
      ,CASE WHEN MAX(TheDate) = MIN(TheDate) 
            THEN NULL
            ELSE CONVERT(time, MAX(TheDate))
       END AS EndHour
FROM #T
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT CONVERT(date, TheDate) AS DateOnly
     ) AS CA1
GROUP BY UserID
        ,DateOnly
```

Comment: both solutions work but I prefer this because it is the simplest